# Can somebody, in USA, have an official and unofficial date and place of arrest?

Tags: arrest

Dumitru Popescu, the CEO of ARCA Space Corporation, (a strange mixture of a scammer, inventor and man with mental problems who made a lot of noise in newspapers regarding his inventions) was arrested in the United States.

Finally, [**he posted a video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0gZLdLTmiY) with explanations for his followers.

The problem is that D. Popescu claims he was arrested by custom officers, in Atlanta, on Oct. 24, 2017. However, [**in his arrest record**](http://www.donaanacounty.org/inmates/viewprofile_archived/1700009732), which is available on the internet, it is clearly written this:  "Arrest Date/Time: 11-08-17 06:15", "Location: JONESBORO, GA".

It is true, JONESBORO is close to the airport of Atlanta but is about 15 km away. Neither the location nor the date of arrest matches the ones claimed by D. Popescu. Who is lying who is telling the truth?

Jason Gibbs, the author of the article "Arca CEO Dumitru Popescu says he's innocent and will continue working" that appeared in Las Cruces Sun-News, is one of the people who remarked this discrepancy.

When asked why the place and date of arrest pretended by D. Popescu do not coincide with what is written is his file, ARCA SPACE gave this answer:

*We noticed this discrepancy as well. He was arrested Oct 24th at the airport in Atlanta, and was transferred to police custody who took him to Clayton County Jail. It appears the error occurred when he was transferred from Clayton County to Doña Ana County. The arrest date of Oct 24th was acknowledged by the court during his first hearing in Doña Ana, so we aren't sure why it's listed differently on their website.*

**Can somebody have an official and unofficial date and place of arrest in the United States?**

Comment: I think that the real question is whether jail booking authorities can make clerical errors that don't get promptly corrected (at least in this case) and the answer to that question is yes, although it isn't really a legal one.

Comment: It can not be a simple mistake because both the place and date of arrest are apparently wrong which is an unlikely double error and also because the news about the arrest of D. Popescu surfaced in newspapers immediately after Nov. 8 not Oct 24. 2017.

Comment: On what basis do you claim that two related errors (not two distinct separate errors) are unlikely to occur, or that when they occur, would occur together?

Comment: Have you watched the video and studied D. Popescu's arrest record (I gave links to these two items) before asking questions?

Comment: You're making a statement about likelihoods. That doesn't depend on any individual circumstance, by definition.

Comment: @RobertWerner I can imagine all sorts of ways that a double error could occur. For example, suppose that someone starts entering an arrest into a database, gets up to get a donut, and before returning someone drops another arrest to be entered into the database on top of the original file, and the person continues entering it in without realizing it is a new file. Or, someone has an autofill function on their computer, accidentally types the wrong first letter, the rest of the fields populate based upon an arrest entered earlier, they accidentally hit enter, and aren't bothered to fix it.

Comment: My question is quite clear: "Can somebody have an official and unofficial date and place of arrest in the United States?" Can somebody be taken from the street and brought to a detention center today while the official arrest date is finally recorded after some time as 7 days from now? There are legislations where one is not considered arrested even if  he is in a prison cell before a judge determines that that person must be arrested.